# Bokeh embed not working in Flask (Bokeh is not defined)

Tags: javascript, python, flask, embed, bokeh

I am trying to load a bokeh figure in my flask app and I can't get the plot to render in my template. I am using bokeh.embed components in exactly the same way that it's done in all the examples:

```
script1, div1 = components(p)
cdn_js = CDN.js_files[0]
cdn_css = CDN.css_files[0]
```

I then pass the components to render_template like this:

```
return render_template("plot.html", script1=script1, div1=div1, cdn_css=cdn_css, cdn_js=cdn_js )
```

When plot.html loads, it has all the components in it, but for some reason the plot simply isn't displaying. Here's what the scripts look like in the rendered template:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/cyborg/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href=https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.13.min.js type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src=https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.13.min.css></script>
```

The script and div are both in the body and look correct. However I'm getting an error in javascript:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Bokeh is not defined
at HTMLDocument.fn
```

Why am I getting this error if I'm loading the bokeh libraries in the head? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have your CSS and JS loads mixed up. You are loading `bokeh.min.js` in the `<link rel="stylesheet"...>` tag, and loading `bokeh.min.css` in the `<script>` tag.

Comment: That was it. Thanks! :)